# Highstock doesn't show chart

Tags: php, mysql, json, highcharts

I have php file which produce data in JSON format **get_json.php** and file where I want to display chart **grafik.php**.

Code in **get_json.php**

```
<?php
include('config.php');   //connection to DB

$r=("SELECT * FROM data");
$result=mysql_query($r);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$date= strtotime($row['cas'])*1000;   //time in format 2013-03-21 16:23:11 
$values=hexdec($row['data']);         // hex values to decimal
$array[]=array($date, $values);
}

echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

Output of JSON **get_json.php**
   [[1364463576000,46906],[1364463578000,50379],[1364463580000,33733],[1364463582000,5612], [1364463981000,14213],[1364464007000,11208],[1364490137000,38047],[1364665254000,14964],[1364665256000,11443],[1364665257000,9005],[1364665259000,5283],[1364665260000,1731]]

Code in **grafik.php**

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>

   <script>
     $(function() {
  $.getJSON('http://localhost/testing10/get_json.php', function(data) {


    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1
        },

        title : {
            text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },

        series : [{
            name : 'AAPL Stock Price',
            data : data,
            marker : {
                enabled : true,
                radius : 3
            },
            shadow : true,
            tooltip : {
                valueDecimals : 2
            }
        }]
    });
});
});

</script>
 <div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I dont know where I did a mistake, if anybody see some mistake please help me to solve this.
I am trying to do chart where on X-axis will be time and on Y-axis proper value.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages in the browsers console?

Comment: call jquery library above highstock.js

Comment: This error appears..but i dont know how to improve it[LINK](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/35284336/err.JPG)

Comment: @TamilSelvan Thank you! The chart is now visible:)

Answer (score 0):

I got your data working:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
 rangeSelector: {
     selected: 1
 },

 title: {
     text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
 },
 series: [{
     name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
     data: [
         [1364463576000, 46906],
         [1364463578000, 50379],
         [1364463580000, 33733],
         [1364463582000, 5612],
         [1364463981000, 14213],
         [1364464007000, 11208],
         [1364490137000, 38047],
         [1364665254000, 14964],
         [1364665256000, 11443],
         [1364665257000, 9005],
         [1364665259000, 5283],
         [1364665260000, 1731]
     ],
     marker: {
         enabled: true,
         radius: 3
     },
     shadow: true,
     tooltip: {
         valueDecimals: 2
     }
 }]
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3A3bK/

I had to change the fist line from:

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
```

to

```
$('#container').highcharts({
```